# I am making a BMI calculator with HTML, JavaScript and node.js but when I click submit, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am making a BMI (Body Mass Index) calculator with HTML, JavaScript,  and one of its frameworks Node.js. But when I click the 'submit' button, nothing happens, not even an error. Why is this?

Here is my code.

My **HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BMI Calculator</title>
</head>
<h1>BMI Calculator</h1>
<form action="/bmiCalculator" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Weight" placeholder="Weight">
</form>
<input type="text" name="Height" placeholder="height"></br>
<button type="submit">Calculate</button>

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

My **JavaScript**:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get('/bmiCalculator', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/bmiCalculator.html")
});

app.post('/bmiCalculator', function(req, res) {
    var Weight = parseFloat(req.body.Weight);
    var Height = parseFloat(req.body.Height);
    var bmi = Weight / (Height * Height);

    res.send("Your BMI is " + bmi);
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server Started on Port 3000");
});
```

I use VS-Code as my default text editor and I go to http://localhost:3000/bmiCalculator to preview my code. I already installed express and body-parser using hyper-terminal.

Comment: Do you see any issues in your browser's dev-tools console? You can use the _Network_ panel to make sure a POST request is made with the appropriate data and also inspect the raw response

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. You have a `</form>` after your first `<input>`. Remove that. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: If your FE is running on a different port than BE you'll need to give the full API URL in action.

Comment: @HarshSaini _"If your FE is running on a different port than BE"_... it's not

Comment: Thanks Phil... It worked. I owe you one man.

Comment: This question will become eligible for deletion tomorrow.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

HTML Part:

```
<form action="/bmiCalculator" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="Weight" placeholder="Weight" />
  <input type="text" name="Height" placeholder="height" />
  <input type="submit">Calculate</input>
</form>
```

Node.Js Part:

```
app.post('/bmiCalculator', (req, res) => {
    const Weight = parseFloat(req.body.Weight);
    const Height = parseFloat(req.body.Height);
    const bmi = Weight/(Height * Height);
    res.send("Your BMI is " + bmi);
});
```

Try this. May be this will resolve your queries

Comment: I have not voted, but I assume the downvote was for answering a typo question. The question will probably be deleted in the future, and it is easier to delete if there are no accepted answers.

Answer (score -1):

I think you've got an issue in the form section, let me know if the solution works.

```
<form action="/bmiCalculator" method="post">
<input type="text" name="Weight" placeholder="Weight">
<input type="text" name="Height" placeholder="height">
<input type="submit">Calculate</input>
</form>
```

Comment: I have not voted, but I assume the downvote was for answering a typo question. The question will probably be deleted in the future, and it is easier to delete if there are no accepted answers.